# Is this a good way to speed up array processing?

Tags: arrays, list, arraylist

So, today I woke up with this single idea.

Just supouse you have a *long list of things*, an array, and you have to check each one of those to find the one that matches what you're looking for. To do this, you could maybe use a `for` loop. Now, imagine that the one you're looking for is almost at the end of the list but you don't know it. So, in that case, asuming it doesn't matter the order in which you check the elements of the list, it would be more convinient for you to start from the last element rather than the first one just to *save some time and memory* maybe. But then, what if your element is almost at the beggining?

That's when I thought: what if I could start checking the elements from both ends of the list *at the same time*?

So, after several tries, I came up with this raw sample code (which is written in js) that, in my opinion, would solve what we were defining above:

```
fx (var list) {
    var len = length(list);

    // To save some time as we were saying, we could check first if the array isn't as long as we were expecting
    if (len == 0) {
        // If it's not, then we just process the only element anyway
        /*
        ...
        list[0]
        ...
        */
        return;
    } else {
        // So, now here's the thing. The number of loops won't be the length of the list but just half of it.
        for (var i = 0; i == len/2; i++) {
            // And inside each loop we process both the first and last elements and so on until we reach the middle or find the one we're looking, whatever happens first
            /*
            ...
            list[i]
            list[len]
            ...
            */
            len--;
        }
    }

    return;
};
```

Anyway, I'm still not totally sure about if this would really speed up the process or make it slower or not making any difference at all. That's why I need your help, guys.

In your own experience, what do you think? Is this really a good way to make this kind of process faster? If it is or it isn't, why? Is there a way to improve it?

Thanks, guys.

Comment: Generally it's a good idea to specify the language your using when posting code.

Comment: Well, i wasn't talking about specifically one language but you're right. Let's supouse it's written is js which is the one i feel more comfortable with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proposed algorithm is good *if* you know that the item is likely to be at the beginning or end but not in the middle, bad if it's likely to be in the middle, and merely overcomplicated if it's equally likely to be anywhere in the list.

In general, if you have an **unsorted** list of *n* items then you potentially have to check all of them, and that will always take time which is *at least proportional to n* (this is roughly what the notation “O(*n*)” means) — there are no ways around this, other than starting with a sorted or partly-sorted list.

In your scheme, the loop runs for only *n*/2 iterations, but it does about twice as much work in each iteration as an ordinary linear search (from one end to the other) would, so it's roughly equal in total cost.

If you do have a partly-sorted list (that is, you have some information about where the item is more likely to be), then starting with the most likely locations first is a fine strategy. (Assuming you're not frequently looking for items which aren't in the list at all, in which case nothing helps you.)

Answer (score 1):

If you work from both ends, then you'll get the worst performance when the item you're looking for is near the middle. No matter what you do, sequential searching is O(n).

If you want to speed up searching a list, you need to use a better data structure, such as a sorted list, hash table, or B-tree.